# ionic and cordova install failed: invalid portocol: null

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I try to install ionic and cordova with npm and i get error in console:
[image: console]

**And npm-debug content is:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\nodejs\\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'install',

1 verbose cli   '-g',

1 verbose cli   'ionic' ]

2 info using npm@3.10.8

3 info using node@v6.9.1

4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting

5 silly install loadCurrentTree

6 silly install readGlobalPackageData

7 silly fetchPackageMetaData ionic

8 silly fetchNamedPackageData ionic

9 silly mapToRegistry name ionic

10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry

11 silly mapToRegistry registry registry.npmjs.org

12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {

12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'ionic',

12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,

12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'ionic',

12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'ionic',

12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',

12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',

12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }

13 silly mapToRegistry uri registry.npmjs.org/ionic

14 verbose request uri registry.npmjs.org/ionic

15 verbose request no auth needed

16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:26:19

17 verbose request id 6f731768ad7d892d

18 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/ionic

19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Invalid protocol: null

20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 11:26:29

21 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/ionic

22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Invalid protocol: null

23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 11:27:29

24 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/ionic

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: Invalid protocol: null

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.init (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:460:31)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at new Request 
(C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:129:8)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at request (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:55:10)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:158:13)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at RetryOperation._fn 
(C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:68:10)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for ionic Error: Invalid protocol: null

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.init (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:460:31)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at new Request 
(C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:129:8)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at request (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:55:10)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:158:13)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at RetryOperation._fn (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:68:10)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting

27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing

28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing

29 silly install printInstalled

30 verbose stack Error: Invalid protocol: null

30 verbose stack     at Request.init (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:460:31)

30 verbose stack     at new Request (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:129:8)

30 verbose stack     at request (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:55:10)

30 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:158:13)

30 verbose stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17

30 verbose stack     at RetryOperation._fn (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)

30 verbose stack     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:68:10)

30 verbose stack     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)

30 verbose stack     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)

30 verbose stack     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

31 verbose cwd C:\Users\amaso\Desktop\ws

32 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393

33 error argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"

34 error node v6.9.1

35 error npm  v3.10.8

36 error Invalid protocol: null

38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: on which os you are trying to install?

Comment: it's windows 10..